# Solr Synonyms with levenshtein distance

Tags: solr

Hi I am working on nickname mapping thru SynonymFilterFactory.

For example, if I search for john, i will get john, jonny, jon, jack, jackie, jacky and johnny from the SynonymFilterFactory and I would like to apply fuzzy 
search/levenshtein distance on the return nicknames such as jonny~, jon~, 
jack~, jackie~ and johnny~, it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can just use SynonymFileFactory as usual, and send a fuzzy query. The terms in the synonym file are matched against the query input, so if your query input has the fuzzy operator, it will do what you want.